# How to Retrieve the Definitions of a Word from WordNet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I was trying to find a way to get just the definition(s) of a given word from WordNet from NLTK. I tried the following code, but I got an error saying 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'definition':

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

definition = wordnet.definition('game')
print(definition)
```

I tried to look in many books but found no relevant information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at https://pythonprogramming.net/wordnet-nltk-tutorial/, I think the answer would be:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet


syns = wordnet.synsets("game")
print(syns[0].definition())
```

Comment: Try to run it for the word ""tablessss". You get a definition, but this is not a word in English.

Comment: @NathanB It's now